# “Text Grid: Scale Times” feature for applying values from one sound file to an existing textgrid

Tags: praat

If I have an existing sound file (Sound1) and a corresponding, hand-annotated file(TextGrid1), can I use the ‘Scale Times’ feature on TextGrid1 using another sound file(Sound2)’s duration tier so that Sound2 has a textgrid?

TextGrid1 has two tiers.
Sound1 and Sound2 do not have the same durations, but need the exact same labels in their textgrids.

Any helpful articles or tutorials on using this feature would be welcome. (my search yielded no useful results).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want a version of TextGrid1 which matches the duration of Sound2, like:

```
selectObject: "TextGrid TextGrid1"
Copy: "TextGrid2"
selectObject: "Sound Sound2"
dur = Get total duration
selectObject: "TextGrid TextGrid2"
Scale times to: 0, dur
```

So you create a copy of TextGrid1, then get the duration of Sound2, then scale TextGrid2 to match that duration.

Comment: No problem. Definitely something to automate if you're normalizing a lot of textgrids.